# Cannot get an onclick event to work in the default Shopify Debut Theme

Tags: javascript, html, shopify

I have added the following code as a section in the Shopify Debut Theme:

```
            <div class="fullscreen-video-wrap
                        fullscreen-video-wrap--{{ section.settings.height }}
                        fullscreen-video-wrap--{{ section.id }}">
                <video class="video-js" autoplay preload playsinline muted
                    poster="https:{{ section.settings.image | img_url: 'master' }} controlsList="nofullscreen">
                    <source src="{{ section.settings.newvideo_link }}" type="video/mp4">
                    </source>
                </video>
            </div>
```

as to include a MP4 video. However, if I change the code to something as simple as this:

```
                <video class="video-js" autoplay preload playsinline muted
                    poster="https:{{ section.settings.image | img_url: 'master' }} controlsList="nofullscreen" onclick="alert("I am an alert box!");">
```

The alert button will not work. So I have been starting to debug, what is hijacking the onclick event using Chrome > Inspect > Sources and then breakpoint at the click event. I got the following:

[image: Click event hijack]

I would like to know how to continue and how to resolve this issue? I am also not quite familiar with LazySizes and am wondering how I could make the "onclick" event work.

Comment: Looks like a missing end-quote for the `poster` attribute: `poster="https:{{ section.settings.image | img_url: 'master' }}" controlsList="nofullscreen">` - note the added quote just before "controlsList". Also, the second example with alert will fail for the same reason as well as too many quotes within the alert.  Should be: `poster="https:{{ section.settings.image | img_url: 'master' }}" controlsList="nofullscreen" onclick="alert('I am an alert box!');"`

Comment: Thanks Metro, unfortunately, it still does not seem to work.